# Nginx limit_conn in IF statement?

Tags: nginx

How to make possible something like this?

```
   location /download/ {
      limit_conn addr 2;

      if ($arg_C) {
          limit_conn addr 1;
      }
   }
```

Gives me:

```
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] "limit_conn" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www.mypage.com:60
```

Comment: if you get no answer, please ask this in the [nginx-forum](http://forum.nginx.org/)